# Download shared file with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have to get data from a excel document which is shared with me. I have to get the cell colors of a lot of cells which takes very long with the graph api since you can only get them cell by cell. So i would like to download it and process it offline.

However since the file is not on my drive I'm not getting the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` field with the file details request, and I would need to go with the [Download File](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content) endpoint, which unfortunately returns 404. Is there any suggestion how can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

According to your questions, you want to download a file which is someone shared with you. If I have misunderstand your, please let me know.

I have a preliminary solution like this:

First, we can use the [List items shared with the signed-in user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_sharedwithme) API to get the file which is shared with you. The part of the response like this:

```
{
  "id": "1312abc",
  "remoteItem": {
    "id": "{itemid}",
    "name": "March Proposal.docx",
    "file": { },
    "size": 19121,
    "parentReference": {
      "driveId": "{driveid}",
      "id": "1991210caf!104"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

From the response, we can get the drive's id and the item's id of the shared file.

Second, we can use the drive's id and the item's id to download the file. The API like this:

`GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content`

For more detail, we can refer to the content of [Download the contents of a DriveItem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content)

Comment: As I said, the /content endpoint gives a 404 error for some reason.

Comment: Did you assign the correct  `itemId` parameter? If so, could you show your request and response results?